# Is there any common Swift coding conventions?

Tags: swift

At my work, I need to do some iOS coding using Swift version 4, which, needless to say, I have never done. As I would like to write from scratch code that is "maintainable" in some sense, I have to ask the question in the title.

Comment: I think you need to follow Apple official documentation regarding this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Compatibility.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.

1. First is [API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/) by Apple;
2. Second one is very popular [Swift style guide by Ray Wenderlich team](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide);
3. Also, i suggest you to use [`SwiftLint`](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) framework, that almost for free helps to find all non-conventions problems in your code.